# Mongoid Errors When Doing Model.first

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, mongoid3

I just upgraded to Mongoid 3, but I'm having a very strange issue.

I have a model called "Event" and another called "Team" - each has has_and_belongs_to_many relationship.

After upgrading, I simply can't do Event.first or Event.last on the console. I get this error in the console:

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

The error occurs in `set_on_parent` in mongoid (4.0.0.alpha1) `lib/mongoid/relations/eager/base.rb`

What's strange is that Team.first (and all my other models) work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out in my Event class I had a `default_scope includes(:teams)`. Removing that cleared up the error.